# UISearchBar keeps falling down when click search by using custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have `UISearchBar` in my app which is subview by another main view.

I have searched for many answers already on `stackoverflow` but seems not help for me. What i have found in `stackoverflow` they advice me to add `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` and `definesPresentationContext = true` but still my `UISearchBar` keeps fall down every time I click on searchBar.
So, I decided to ask my own question and I am sure that you will consider this as duplicate question.

I don't use `tableView`.

Here is the main view of `UISearchBar`

```
private func setupSearchBarView() {
    searchBarView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    self.searchBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.searchBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.searchBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.searchBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56 ).isActive = true
}
```

Here is `searchController.searchBar`

```
func setupSearchBar(){
    self.searchBarViewHeight = searchController.searchBar.frame.height

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = BaseColor.colorBlack
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = BaseColor.colorAccentDark
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

}
```

[image: Here is the result]

I don't know why it always keeps shift down all the time I start filtering.

Comment: Have you figure it out? I also facing this problem.

Comment: explain what shift down means? its not staying pinned to top of the screen? try to provide a complete demo in a playground so we can reproduce

Comment: @Scriptable Yes! I meant that its not staying pinned to top of the screen.